# What is the variance of a constant?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, variance

Given a constant $c$, I know that $\text{E}(c)=c$, but what about the variance of $c$?

Comment: It's just $0$...look up the definition of variance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have observed that, for any constant $\alpha$, $E[\alpha]=\alpha$, then we have
$$
\operatorname{Var}(c)=\operatorname{E}[c^2]-(\operatorname{E}[c])^2=c^2-c^2=0.
$$ One may also just go back to the definition of the variance,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{E}\left[(X - \operatorname{E}\left[X \right])^2 \right]
$$ giving

> $$
> \operatorname{Var}(c)= \operatorname{E}\left[(c - c)^2 \right]=\operatorname{E}\left[0 \right]=0.
> $$

Comment: It won't let me edit, but E[(X-E[(X])^2] should be E[(X-E[X])^2] (typo).

Comment: @student Edited, thank you.